# IDE for javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to javascript and have been assigned to work on with java script and dojo.

My question is which is the best IDE for javascript (dojo) development. I am currently using eclipse for java development.

But it seems while writing js on jsp / html it is not giving me hints or syntax available ?

Comment: Try NetBeans for PHP or maybe JetBrains WebStorm. Eclipse will do fine as well, I believe, but probably requires appropriate plugins to handle JavaScript.

Comment: Java and JavaScript (note: no space!) are two entirely different things. Please don't confuse them.

Comment: One tip is to not write JavaScript in the web page/JSP.  Make sure it is always imported from a separate `.js` file and most editors will deal better with it.  The same principle holds true of embedding styles (CSS/`.css`) in the JSP/HTML.

Comment: You don't need an IDE for Javascript. With a text editor as Sublimetext and a browser with Javascript console you can do it all